# Iframe Form Tracking with Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-analytics

I am trying to track the trafic on an **Iframe Form** (for job application).
Things to know:

- I can modify the Iframe Page body... but not the header (owned solution)
- I added the 'link' option for cross-domain tracking

Issues :

- I can track the trafic on Ga account, but the detailed pages urls are not dislpayed... I have 1 line with the domain name only !

**Alternate question:**
Is it possible to add regex condition into the Ga tag ?
Like :   ga('send', 'pageview', '**^iframe.domain.com/***);

**Note 1 :**
The form generates urls with many parameters... but still there are some distinct pages on it :

- iframe.domain.com/**form**?paramètre1=1&paramètre2=2&paramètre3=3
- iframe.domain.com/**form-validation**?paramètre1=1&paramètre2=2&paramètre3=3

**Note 2 :**
My GA code added into the Iframe :

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXX-01">
</script>
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());
ga('create', 'UA-XXX-01', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
ga('require', 'linker');
ga('linker:autoLink', ['www.domain.com', 'iframe.domain.com']);
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: You don't need cross-domain tracking for traffic between subdomains - `cookieDomain=auto` in your GA snippet. Do you use a Real Time report to check? Did you wait 24 hours to see data in standard reports?

Comment: My example urls were misleading... The Iframe is on a different domain. It is like : ga('linker:autoLink', ['www.domain.com', 'iframe.com']);